# Making qsub block until job is done?

Tags: performance, shell, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, qsub

Currently, I have a driver program that runs several thousand instances of a "payload" program and does some post-processing of the output.  The driver currently calls the payload program directly, using a `shell()` function, from multiple threads.  The `shell()` function executes a command in the current working directory, blocks until the command is finished running, and returns the data that was sent to stdout by the command.  This works well on a single multicore machine.  I want to modify the driver to submit `qsub` jobs to a large compute cluster instead, for more parallelism.

Is there a way to make the `qsub` command output its results to stdout instead of a file and block until the job is finished?  Basically, I want it to act as much like "normal" execution of a command as possible, so that I can parallelize to the cluster with as little modification of my driver program as possible.

Edit:  I thought all the grid engines were pretty much standardized.  If they're not and it matters, I'm using Torque.

Answer (score 4):

You don't mention what queuing system you're using, but SGE supports the '-sync y' option to qsub which will cause it to block until the job completes or exits.

Answer (score 2):

In TORQUE this is done using the -x and -I options. qsub -I specifies that it should be interactive and -x  says run only the command specified. For example:

```
qsub -I -x myscript.sh
```

will not return until myscript.sh finishes execution.

Comment: Don't you lose the ability to store the output in output files?

Comment: You lost the automatic storing of output this way, but you can log your terminal session and save the output that way.

Answer (score 1):

In PBS you can use `qsub -Wblock=true <command>`